# Break PHP while loop if variable is empty

Tags: php

I have a CSV (attached below) that I am looping through with PHP. Note: the `Peter` entry is missing an `Extension` number.

How do I break the loop if any $cell (like `Extension`) is empty

```
<?php
echo "<html><body><table>\n\n";
$f = fopen("users.csv", "r");
while (($line = fgetcsv($f)) !== false) {
        echo "<tr>";
        foreach ($line as $cell) {
                echo "<td>" . htmlspecialchars($cell) . "</td>";
        }
        echo "</tr>\n";
}
fclose($f);
echo "\n</table></body></html>";
```

~

```
Forename,Surname,Extension
Jim,Carey,1973
Peter,Robertson,
```

Comment: `if (empty($cell)) { break; }`

Comment: You answer your own question in your question: break

Comment: @u_mulder Can you tell me where this should go? I tried to add it immediately after my `foreach` loop but no success, it still outputs rows even if it's blank.

Comment: Do you want to break the inner or outer loop?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using this -

```
<?php
echo "<html><body><table>\n\n";
$f = fopen("users.csv", "r");
while (($line = fgetcsv($f)) !== false) {
    $row = "<tr>";
    $is_empty = false;
    foreach ($line as $cell) {
        if ($cell !== '') {
            $row .= "<td>" . htmlspecialchars($cell) . "</td>";
        } else {
            $is_empty = true;
        }
    }
    $row .= "</tr>\n";
    if ($is_empty) {
        continue;
    } else {
        echo $row;
    }
}
fclose($f);
echo "\n</table></body></html>";
?>
```

This solution will print the row only if all the fields have value. You can use break instead of continue, if you want to break the loop.